# Granular media permissions instead of READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on Android 13 (SDK 33)

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I found my app get crazy after I upgraded `targetSdk` for 33 (Android 13).
That happens due to this change:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

The `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not supported anymore and any attempt to request this permission from the user results with permission denial result which actually breaks my app.

According to above link, Google replaced `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` with 3 new permissions `READ_MEDIA_IMAGE`, `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO` and `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`

Neither of them works for my case.

I just need to allow my user pick up any files (in my case subtitles files like `srt`, text files etc + video files) on the device file system.

E.g. user can copy some files by USB cable onto `Download`, `Documents` or even some new folder anywhere(!) and I need to get access to it.

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I replace `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to be able to search and load any files from my device file system
2. How to support pre Android 13 devices? Should I still support `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` alongside with the new approach whatever it is?

I need a file picker for the device file system and be able to use the String filepath received from that file picker to access file by standard Java file I/O operations.

Thanks.

If I try keep requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it does not show up the permission dialog to the user anymore on Android 13 and always results with permission deny.

If I request only `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO` it seems working for the video files. And I even can see non-video files (srt) at `Download` folder.

Attempt to request 2 permissions all together fail and block the option menu buttons on the toolbar:

```java
        permissionRequest.launch(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO});
```

I know about `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but I'm afraid Google won't allow me to use it to access the full file system for my file pickup dialog and use the filepath later at my Java code.

Comment: "I need a file picker for the device file system" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. "and be able to use the String filepath received from that file picker to access file by standard Java file I/O operations" -- you will need to relax that requirement somewhat.

Comment: You can access the user to select a file from any location and read the contents of that file without needing any storage permissions on all API levels (something talked about even [7 years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA)). What makes you think you need any permission at all to read a file the user specifically gives you access to?

Comment: @CommonsWare would you be able to see the folder and it's content created by the user using USB connection to Windows? What about content created by some other app?

Comment: You will not have access to content in the root of external storage, nor in app-specific external storage (e.g., `Android/data/some.application.id.goes.here/`). Otherwise, you should be in OK shape.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just did quick test and it looks like working pretty good even without permission was granted. However my concern is how it would work for older SDK versions. I have `minSdkVersion=16`. And thank you for that solution!

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` was added in API Level 19. At this point, I cannot recommend developers support back older than that.